# How do I get two way binding to work in Angular with new controllerAs syntax and Object Oriented Controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-5

I am fearful of "scope soup", people hanging too much functionality off the $scope. So I am experimenting with OO oriented controllers, the new controllerAs and using EC5 style getter / setters in my controller. That is working sweet, but now I want to bind my directive's scope to my controller's scope two way, and it isn't working as I expect. I have created this codePen to show it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DlfxB?editors=101

I expect this line to work:

```
scope: { pants: '='},
```

Comment: I don't fully grasp what you are trying to achieve, but how about this pen ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzmiC

Comment: @Bonatoc OP wants to attach the properties to the controller instance of the directive and not directly to the scope. BUt ultimately everything is n scope. controller alias becomes a property on the scope.

Comment: @Botanoc, your example is bound directly to the EC5 controller, I don't want that. The directive should only be aware of the property it is bound to. I am trying to mix a few ideas together, EC5 getters and setters (which is insanely awesome if you look close), the controller as an object (oo controller) and then double bound to a directive's local scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`bindToController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) option if you are in 1.3 rc version, to have the 2 way bound scope variables to be bound on the controller. Otherwise you would have to just manually map the properties to controller instance (Which is a pain) or just use regular syntax (without controller.) for 2 way bound properties. So you could do `'<h1>{{my.pants}} - myDirective.pants = {{ my.pants }}</h1><input ng-model="my.pants">'` with `bindToController:true` in the directive configuration.

> `bindToController`
>
> - When an isolate scope is used for a component (see above), and `controllerAs` is used, `bindToController` will
> - allow a component to have its properties bound to the controller, rather than to scope. When the controller
> - is instantiated, the initial values of the isolate scope bindings are already available.

```js
(function(){
    
   var myApp = angular.module('plunker', []);

    var helloEC5 = function(){
      this.pants = "jeans";
    };
    helloEC5.prototype = {
        firstName: 'Seeya',
        lastName: 'Latir',
        get fullName() {
            return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
        },
        set fullName (name) {
            var words = name.toString().split(' ');
            this.firstName = words[0] || '';
            this.lastName = words[1] || '';
        }
    };
    myApp.controller('HelloEC5', helloEC5);
    myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
          scope: { pants: '='},
          controllerAs: 'my',
          controller: function(){},
          bindToController:true,
          template: '<h1>{{my.pants}} - myDirective.pants = {{ my.pants }}</h1><input ng-model="my.pants">'
        }
    });
 })();
```

```html
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-rc.1" data-semver="1.3.0-rc.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.js"></script>

  <div ng-app="plunker">
    <div ng-controller="HelloEC5 as EC5">
      <p>HelloEC5 says my name is: {{EC5.fullName}} wearing {{EC5.pants}}!</p>
      <label>Pants:</label>
      <input ng-model="EC5.pants" type="text" />
      <label>FirstName:</label>
      <input ng-model="EC5.firstName" type="text" />
      <div my-directive="" pants="EC5.pants"></div>
      <hr />
      <label>Setting HelloEC5.fullName:</label>
      <input ng-model="EC5.fullName" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: PSL - is this a good use of EC5 getters and setters?I really like how clean this looks. I see people go crazy with $scope.getVar() and $scope.setVar() when the language does this, and custom hooks natively.

Comment: @Httpete Sorry i did not get your question. Using get set is fine, if you are ok not supporting older browsers. Angular has a version of getter setter for ngModel. But it is different from ES5 getter setter.. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: I am completely fine leaving IE <10 in the dustbin of history. My problem is I have lots of scope.soup(). The examples in angular doc are too simplistic, and are most people's starting point. OO controllers and controllerAs are very attractive. I just want to know if I need something like https://github.com/Baqend/jahcode or I can just use what I just laid out. Thoughts most welcome..

Comment: @PSL `bindToController` was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!