# Two way data binding with directive doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I have a controller used to add tasks.  On that page a user needs to select a group to act upon. I have written a directive that is used to allow a user to pick groups (folders)

My page controller

```
function AddTaskController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.group = { whatsit: true };

    $scope.$watch("vm.group", function () {
        console.log("controller watch", vm.group);
    },true);
}
```

The page html where the directive is used

```
<em-group-selection group="vm.group"></em-group-selection>
```

The directive configuration

```
function GroupSelectionDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {
            group: '='
        },
        controller: GroupSelectionDirectiveController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/views/templates/common/folderselection.html'
    };
}
```

The directive controller:

```
function GroupSelectionDirectiveController($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.$watch("group", function () { console.log("yo1", vm.group); }, true)
    $scope.$watch("vm.group", function () { console.log("yo2", vm.group); }, true)
}
```

Now when this fires, both `console.log()` calls in the directive fire once, with `undefined`.  They never fire again.  If in the controller I set `vm.group` to something else the `$watch` in the `AddTaskController` never gets fired.

Why isnt the data binding working?

---

**Update:**

I notice that if, in the directive, I change the `init()` function in my directive to use `$scope` it works!  Can I not, as Fedaykin suggests, use `controllerAs` with two way data binding?

```
function init() {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.group.shizzy = 'timeout hit';
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: I always have problems using `$scope` mixed with `controllerAs`, I´d suggest you to remove the `controllerAs` syntax and give it a try

Comment: I just noticed that `$scope.group` contains the right structure! The thing is, the `controllerAs` syntax is really nice so I want to use it ;/

Comment: Dude, I found the answer!! In the directive setup use `bindToController:true` and it works!

Comment: Well I rarely use controllers on directives, what if you try to do the watch on the linking function?

Comment: Great! If possible leave the answer here for future reference :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that if you use isolate scopes and `controlelrAs` syntax you need to also use `bindToController : true`.  Without this you will not be able to only use `vm` and will have to use `$scope` for the isolate scope variables

More information can be found in the [John Papa style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y075) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25962436/94278)

The final directive setup is as so:

```
function GroupSelectionDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {
            group: '='
        },
        controller: GroupSelectionDirectiveController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: '/views/templates/common/folderselection.html'
    };
}
```

Comment: _"...and will have to use $scope for the isolate scope variables"_ - Well, you use `$scope` nonetheless.

Comment: Yes, only for `$watch` but its far nicer to use the `vm` notation where possible and helps keep your views nicer

Comment: Sure, but why not go the whole nine yards?

Comment: How can I use `$watch` or equivalent without `$scope`? 'Cos I do want to!